# Huge blank space at bottom of page (Word for Mac, Office 365, August 2019)

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, office365

My dissertation submission MUST have 1" margins left and right, and 1.25" margins top and bottom. I get a huge (1/3 of the page) blank/white space at the bottom of the page on one of my pages. I have unchecked all the orphan/widow/keep together/keep with next options, and I have checked for paragraph breaks and page breaks. All clear there.

I have also played around with the margin control and noticed that when I increase my bottom margin (in situ, with the slider, not in settings) it ADDS to the number of lines from the next page that appear at the bottom of the problem page (the one with the blank space). I read that somewhere in another forum. But I can't just tweak it for fun. I have to have 1.25" margins.

What could be causing this besides those things I listed above? All the other posts I've read list these, but none of them is what is causing it in my case...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check your Page Setup. Did you configure any page margins and header?

Comment: Yes, I do. I MUST according to the requirements of the university. My page margins are 1" left and right and 1.25" top and bottom. My header and footer are 0.5". These are non-negotiable. As I mentioned in my original post, if I drag the bottom margin ruler up (i.e. make the margin BIGGER), it pulls more text into the bottom of that page, where the blank space is. I mentioned it because I thought it might be symptomatic of the problem; that if someone recognized that symptom they might also know how to remedy it. But I cannot use this strategy to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using footnotes? If Word needs to insert a footnote, and the word that the footnote is attached to is too close to the bottom of the page, so that there isn't room to insert the footnote text on that page, Word automatically insets space to force the tagged word onto the next page....so that there's room for it to insert the footnote. Hope that helps?